# In rdlc ReportViewer does not fill data when publish on azure server

Tags: asp.net, rdlc, reportviewer

when run on local pc so perfectly. publish and run on server no RDLC file load on report viewer and not showing and error.

in RDLC property i have "Copy always" and also "content" already available

```
                MasterMFStatusDetail rPTDS = new MasterMFStatusDetail();
                rPTDS.Tables["RPTDS"].Merge(ds.Tables[0], true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
                rPTDS.Tables["Style"].Merge(dsselect.Tables[0], true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
                rPTDS.Tables["MF"].Merge(dsselect.Tables[1], true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
                rPTDS.Tables["THC"].Merge(dsselect.Tables[2], true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
                rPTDS.Tables["DKT"].Merge(dsselect.Tables[3], true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);
                rPTDS.Tables["MasterMFParameters"].Merge(MfParameter, true, MissingSchemaAction.Ignore);

                rvView.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
                rvView.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(reportname);
                ReportDataSource datasource = new ReportDataSource("RPTDS", rPTDS.Tables[0]);
                ReportDataSource datasource1 = new ReportDataSource("Style", rPTDS.Tables[1]);
                ReportDataSource datasource2 = new ReportDataSource("MF", rPTDS.Tables[2]);
                ReportDataSource datasource3 = new ReportDataSource("THC", rPTDS.Tables[3]);
                ReportDataSource datasource4 = new ReportDataSource("DKT", rPTDS.Tables[4]);
                ReportDataSource datasource5 = new ReportDataSource("MasterMFParameters", MfParameter);
                rvView.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
                rvView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource);
                rvView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource1);
                rvView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource2);
                rvView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource3);
                rvView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource4);
                rvView.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(datasource5);
                rvView.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

---Aspx Page-----------------------------------------------------

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MasterMFStatusDetailview.aspx.cs" Inherits="LNCReport.Reports.MasterMFStatusDetail.MasterMFStatusDetailview" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">        
        if (typeof (Sys) !== 'undefined') {
            Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(function (sender, args) {
                { { scopeName } } _init();
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePartialRendering="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="rvView" runat="server" Style="width: auto; height: auto">
            <LocalReport EnableHyperlinks="True">
            </LocalReport>
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can we see your aspx page code too. This is not enough to go on here.

Comment: @SalikRafiq please check my aspx page

Comment: what is `reportname` in your code. Ensure that `reportname` is a relative path and than convert this to absolute. Have you tried putting that relative path into the ASPX and seeing if that works on your server?

Comment: @SalikRafiq i have used Server.Mappath() for get a report path. And in server.mappath i have passed a reportname like a Server.MapPath("MasterMFStatusDetail.rdlc").

Comment: @SalikRafiq Please tell me what to do next

Comment: try putting the path to the report in the ASPX instead and see if that works or use the `~` on the path like `Server.MapPath("~/MasterMFStatusDetail.rdlc")`

Comment: @SalikRafiq ok i will try

Comment: @SalikRafiq this is not working please give another solution

Comment: Can I ask if when you publish the app if you are also pre-compiling the reports as well. As far as I can recall that won't work. So what you have to do is have a script which overwrites the deployed rdlc files with the originals. And make sure you have the  ReportViewerControl NuGet also deployed in the bin folder.